# How to return values from a "for" loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make a loop go through a provided string and return `False` if a character that is not recognized is found, and `True` if all the characters are recognized. I do realize that `for` loops don't allow for returning values within them, but considering this is part of a bigger code I need to return a `bool` value as opposed to printed.

Is there a way of figuring this issue out without the `for` loop? My code is below.

(I am also in an intro class, where many of the built in functions and such we have not learned yet and so I should probably not yet use...any simple ways of getting around this?)

```
    chars = ["o", ".", "\"", "n"]


    def find_characters(s):
        for c in s:
            if c not in chars:
                break

    # IDEALLY WANT
    def find_characters(s):
        for c in s:
            if c not in chars:
                return False
                break
            else:
                return True
```

Comment: You want that if it finds at least one character that isn't recognized return True from the for loop?

Comment: you don't need `break` if you use `return` - because `break` will be never executed. And user `return True` after `for`-loop, not inside.

Comment: Basically. I want that if it finds at least one character that is not recognized that it should return False and stop looking. If everything is recognized I'd like it to return True.

Comment: you can use `return` in `for`-loop - so what is the problem ?

Comment: I've realized that return would need to be outside of the for loop... so below. the issue that I don't know how to fix in that scenario is that no matter what it finds it will always return False.  is there someway to get around that? its because if it finds an  incorrect character and so i break it out of the loop it  return false, yet if it runs through all the characters and they are recognized, it will still reach the return false statement and also return false.

Comment: if I run it in the for loop it will  only judge the first  character of the provided string. I only find using break avoids thihs

Comment: Added question: i realize to check for "\" i had to add an extra quotation so that it would be judged as a string, but this also means that the code only recognizes \" as a valid character. any way of avoiding this?

Answer (score 5):

```
def find_characters(s):
    for c in s:
        if c not in chars:
            return False
     return True
```

Based on the comments, I think this is what you want.

Comment: Added question: i realize to check for "\" i had to add an extra quotation so that it would be judged as a string, but this also means that the code only recognizes \" as a valid character. any way of avoiding this?

Comment: change "\"" to '"'(single-quote, double-quote, single-quote). That should fix your issue.

Answer (score 4):

If your provided string is `s`, then you can check your condition and return with:

```
def find_characters(s):
    return all(c in chars for c in s)
```

Comment: this also works. thank you :). Added question: i realize to check for "\" i had to add an extra quotation so that it would be judged as a string, but this also means that the code only recognizes \" as a valid character. any way of avoiding this?

Comment: @sarahsss: Just use `"\\"` which is a standard way to represent a single backslash character in a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

you can use yield to return the multiple values from a loop:

```
def createGenerator():
    mylist = range(3)
    for i in mylist:
        yield i*i

mygenerator = createGenerator() # create a generator
for i in mygenerator:
     print(i)


#output:
0
1
4
```